# How to check whether a value exists among a set of values in a record in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I am using MySQL in such a way that the user enters a date and flights appear on that day.I was too lazy to put many dates so what I did was made certain flights run on certain days.

The table planes contains many columns out of which dtd(column containing many days of type varchar(50)) .

One record(in dtd) is Monday, Tuesday
The user enters the date 2018-12-03 which is a Monday.

My problem is how do I extract only the record which has Monday?(like the monday,Tuesday one)??

I tried select.....where instr(day(2018-12-03),dtd)<>0 but I realised that instr gives 0 in 2 cases
1. the character(s) is not present in the record or 
2.occurence is at the beginning.

Like instr(h,hello) and instr(a,hello) gives 0.

Please help

Comment: Save date(time) as date(time) not as strings.

Comment: No the column dtd has days in it

Comment: Like one record has 'monday,tuesday'

Comment: `'monday,tuesday'` is bad too. Create another table with columns `flight_id (or another id fromt his table) | day`. Data will be there as `1 | monday, 1 | tuesday, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use the `LIKE` operator.
For more info about it please check this link: [SQL Like Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)
To solve your problem, you can try the following:

```
SELECT ...
  WHERE dtd LIKE CONCAT('%', day(2018-12-03), '%');
```

In this case, you will get all the rows of the table, where the value of the field dtd contains the value of day(2018-12-03).
Hope this helps!